# read a line in textfile, put it in listview

Tags: android, listview, text-files

I have two text files in two languages. I need my code to read a line from textfile 1 and textfile 2 and put those in listview that has two textviews. How can I can do this?

my code is here:

```
public class ListViewSoore extends ListActivity{
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_view);
    String itemsen[]=getResources().getStringArray(R.row.pa1);
    adapter=new MyAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.textView1,itemsen);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
    private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, String[] strings) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, strings);
    }

     @Override
    public View getView(int position,View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
                    String itemsen[]=getResources().getStringArray(R.row.pa1);
        String itemsti[]=getResources().getStringArray(R.row.pa2);
        TextView tven=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView tvti=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tven.setText(itemsen[position]);
        tvti.setText(itemsti[position]);
        return row;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I might be a little unsure about what you're trying to accomplish, but define your String array values in the strings.xml file.

A string array included as a rescource should look like this (in the strings.xml file):

```
<string-array name="planets_array">
    <item>Mercury</item>
    <item>Venus</item>
    <item>Earth</item>
    <item>Mars</item>
</string-array>
```